# Connection AlwaysOn AG Listener Problem

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, connectivity, active-directory, sql-server-2014

I'm a newbie for microsoft technologies and I'm having problems in connectivity part for SQL Server 2014. This is probably an easy issue but I'm stuck.

I've 4 servers. One of them is the Active Directory Domain Controller, one is the application server and the others are being used for SQL Servers. Since it's a connectivity issue, IP's for servers are;
**-AD DC : 10.6.0.100 ( Also the DNS Server )
-APP   : 10.6.0.110
-SQL 1 : 10.6.0.120
-SQL 2 : 10.6.0.121**

I've successfully created a failover cluster (DBCLUSTER) and set the IP address of the FC as **10.6.0.130** ( which is **not** an actual server IP, I really don't get this part.. ).

Later, I've created an AlwaysOn Availability Group for sql servers. I've successfully created the AG without listener. I could connect to servers from each other, database syncs without problem. Then, I've created a listener (**AG-LISTENER**) and set it's ip as **10.6.0.131** ( which is **not** an actual server IP, *again*? ) and set it's port to **5525**. It gave no problems.

So I wanted to test connectivity. When I wanted to make connections from **APP** server to directly **SQL 1** or **SQL 2**, I can connect without problem. **But** when I try to connect to **AG-LISTENER**, it cannot find it on network. When I check the DNS records. I can see it as it's being hosted on **10.6.0.131**.

When I tried to ping to **AG-LISTENER** from **AD-DC, APP, SQL 2** servers, it responds that the destination host is unreachable (it's pinging 10.6.0.131 but the response comes from the IP's of AD-DC, APP and SQL 2 servers). *It can connect from SQL 1 server, which is the primary for AG.*

I've checked the firewalls, there's no problem. But I think this is an network issue which I have no clue.

PS: Servers are operating on Windows Server 2012 and are **not** being hosted on Azure.

**SOLUTION**

Cause of the problem was the network topology of the service provider. It's found that IP's 10.6.0.0/32 could be used by other servers of other customers. So they've allocated us another IP block which only we have access to and it worked like a charm.

Comment: The IP address of the cluster is not the physical IP of any specific server because that's the whole point - it sits in front of a set of servers and redirects to whatever server is currently active. If it were set to the physical IP of an actual server, what would happen if that server went down? Nobody would be able to communicate with the virtual cluster name via that IP address...

Comment: Also there is an interesting conversation going on under this post (which also has great information), and the comments show links to other blogs about config which may help: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/system-configuration/dedicated-network-availability-group

Comment: When you say, "Servers are operating on Windows 8," do you mean the Windows 8 desktop OS (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh771457) or Windows Server 2012, formerly known as Windows Server 8 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/hh534429)?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @AaronBertrand, I'll check the link you've shared.

Comment: @dartonw Windows Server 2012

Comment: Check out this list of resources also. It includes a great step by step prereq checklist that might help http://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups/

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried rebooting the SQL Server machines that are members of the cluster? I've had issues in earlier versions of Windows (2003, 2008 R2) where virtual IP addresses would not respond until specific services were restarted, and (obviously) a reboot will restart all services.

Comment: Yes I've tried it. I've found the solution, I'll post the answer if I have enough time..

Answer (score 5):

> It can connect from SQL 1 server, which is the primary for AG.

By "connect", do you mean it can *ping* `AG-LISTENER` from `SQL1`?

It sounds like what your problem might be is with the port number you chose for your listener.  By choosing 5525, you are selecting a non-default port (1433 would be the default).

So when you try to connect to the listener, what does your connection string look like?  I'm guessing it looks something like this:

```
data source = ag-listener; initial catalog = ...
```

You have two options here.  You can either be explicit with your listener's port number:

```
data source = ag-listener,5525; initial catalog = ...
```

Likewise, if you're testing this out with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), then for the **Connect to Server** dialog box, instead of putting in `ag-listener` for the *Server name* text box, put in `ag-listener,5525`.

Or you can change the port that your listener is listening on to 1433 (read the below BOL reference before considering this change):

```
alter availability group YourAvailabilityGroupName
modify listener 'AG-LISTENER'
(
    port = 1433
);
```

It is worth noting when you can use the default port (1433).  Take a look at this reference on [BOL explaining when you can and can't use 1433 for the listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213417.aspx#SelectListenerPort) (excerpt copy/pasted below for reference):

> You can configure the default port to 1433 in order to allow for simplicity of the client connection strings. **If using 1433, you do not need to designate a port number in a connection string.** Also, since each availability group listener will have a separate virtual network name, each availability group listener configured on a single WSFC can be configured to reference the same default port of 1433.
>
> *(portions omitted for brevity)*
>
> If you use the default port of 1433 for availability group listener VNNs, you will still need to **ensure that no other services on the cluster node are using this port**; otherwise this would cause a port conflict.

**EDIT**: If the above isn't your problem (as seen from your comment below) then, after you look through the logs, I'd say the next best course of action is to start looking at the network traffic to see what is (and isn't) happening.  You can use a network monitoring tool like [netmon](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) to accomplish this.

Another thing I'd do, and I realize you said the firewall isn't a problem, but I'd see if the port is actually listening (my favorite tool for this is [portqry](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009)).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer but I've already tried changing the default port to 1433. This is not the issue. It's probably a network issue which is caused by  the topology of the service provider.

Comment: Then it might be time to get out your favorite network monitoring tool and see what is (and isn't) happening.